# How to write an R code which calculates the row-wise mean from an Excel file?

Tags: r, excel, mean

Below is a sample of my data:

```
Dates   User1   User2   User3
Jan-15  10        54    1
Feb-15  25        85    25
Mar-15  69        65    65
Apr-15  56        32    41
```

I do not want to manually make any changes in the excel file.
How can I write an R code to calculate the respective means for Jan, Feb, Mar and Apr.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Did you load the Excel file into R? Also, Have you looked into `rowMeans`?

Comment: 2 questions in one: 1 read Excel file into R, 2 calculate row means. Each has been asked and answered before many many many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use e.g. the [readxl](https://github.com/hadley/readxl) package:

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel(filename, sheetnumber)
rowMeans(df[, -1])
# [1] 21.66667 45.00000 66.33333 43.00000
```